# KeyEvent Not Running

Tags: java, javafx, key

I made a new calculator project JavaFX and Java, but when I tried to add something so that something would be done if this key or that key is pressed, but it would not work and instead prevented the program to run. It would be very helpful if someone has experience on this one, so that I can move on!

My OS is Windows 10. I have imported `KeyCode` and `KeyEvent`, and have tried the answer of "JavaFX KeyEvent not firing" which failed to. I have also tried it without the `scene1.setOnKeyPressed((EventHandler<? super KeyEvent>) root);` which was also a failure. I have linked the action to my FXML document, too.

This is my main class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Essestulator extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
   Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene1 = new Scene(root);
        scene1.setOnKeyPressed((EventHandler<? super KeyEvent>) root);

        stage.setScene(scene1);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

My FXML Controller class:

```java
package calculator

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    double data = 0d;
    int operation = -1;
    private boolean start = false;

    @FXML
    private Label display;

    @FXML
    private Button two;

    @FXML
    private Button five;

    @FXML
    private Button four;

    @FXML
    private Button three;

    @FXML
    private Button one;

    @FXML
    private Button six;

    @FXML
    private Button seven;

    @FXML
    private Button multi;

    @FXML
    private Button add;

    @FXML
    private Button dot;

    @FXML
    private Button divide;

    @FXML
    private Button backspace;

    @FXML
    private Button minus;

    @FXML
    private Button equals;

    @FXML
    private Button clearall;

    @FXML
    private Button clear;

    @FXML
    private Button zero;

    @FXML
    private Button nine;

    @FXML
    private Button eight;

    ArrayList<Integer> arrl = new ArrayList<Integer>(1000);

    @FXML
    void KeyAction(KeyEvent eve) {


        if(start)
        {
            display.setText("");
            start = false;
        }

        if(eve.getSource() == KeyCode.DIGIT1) /* action*/;
        if(eve.getSource() == KeyCode.DIGIT2) /* action*/;
        if(eve.getSource() == KeyCode.DIGIT3) /* action*/;
        if(eve.getSource() == KeyCode.DIGIT4) /* action*/;
        }

    @FXML
    void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

        if(start)
        {
            display.setText("");
            start = false;
        }

        if(event.getSource() == one)
        {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "1");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == two)
        {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "2");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == three)
        {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "3");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == four)
        {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "4");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == five)
        {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "5");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == six)
        {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "6");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == seven)
        {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "7");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == eight)
        {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "8");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == nine)
        {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "9");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == zero)
        {
            display.setText(display.getText() + "0");
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == dot)
        {
            display.setText(display.getText() + ".");
            dot.setDisable(true);
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == clear)
        {
            display.setText("");
            dot.setDisable(false);
        } 
        else if(event.getSource() == add)
        {
            data = Float.parseFloat(display.getText());
            operation = 1;
            display.setText("");
            dot.setDisable(false);
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == minus)
        {
            data = Float.parseFloat(display.getText());
            operation = 2;
            display.setText("");
            dot.setDisable(false);
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == multi)
        {
            data = Float.parseFloat(display.getText());
            operation = 3;
            display.setText("");
            dot.setDisable(false);
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == divide)
        {
            data = Float.parseFloat(display.getText());
            operation = 4;
            display.setText("");
            dot.setDisable(false);
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == equals)
        {
            Float secondOperand = Float.parseFloat(display.getText());
            dot.setDisable(false);
            switch(operation)
            {
                case 1: //Addition
                    Double ans = data + secondOperand;
                    display.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
                    data = ans;
                    break;
                case 2: //Subtraction
                    ans = data - secondOperand;
                    display.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
                    data = ans;
                    break;
                case 3: //Multiplication
                    ans = data * secondOperand;
                    display.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
                    data = ans;
                    break;
                case 4: //Division
                    ans = 0d;
                    try{
                    ans = data / secondOperand;
                    }catch(Exception ex){display.setText("Error");}
                    display.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
                    data = ans;
                    break;
            }
            if(event.getSource() != divide && event.getSource() != add && event.getSource() != multi && event.getSource() != minus)
            {
                start = true;
            }
        }

    }

    @FXML
    private void send2sceneconver(ActionEvent event) throws Exception{
        Parent rootBMI = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ConversionCal.fxml"));

        Scene scene2 = new Scene(rootBMI);
        Stage calS = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

        calS.setScene(scene2);
        calS.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

And my console when I run it:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to javafx.event.EventHandler
    at essestulator.Essestulator.start(Essestulator.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application essestulator.Essestulator
Java Result: 1
```

And my FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="pane" fx:id="window1" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="806.0" prefWidth="1155.0" stylesheets="@FXMLDocument.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="essestulator.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <Line endX="215.0" endY="1.0" layoutX="632.0" layoutY="227.0" startX="-608.0" />
      <GridPane layoutX="23.0" layoutY="244.0" prefHeight="430.0" prefWidth="823.0">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="two" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="109.0" prefWidth="243.0" text="2" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="five" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="216.0" layoutY="115.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="115.0" prefWidth="206.0" text="5" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="four" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="216.0" layoutY="114.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="109.0" prefWidth="243.0" text="4" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="three" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="216.0" layoutY="9.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="109.0" prefWidth="210.0" stylesheets="@FXMLDocument.css" text="3" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="one" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="422.0" layoutY="9.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="109.0" prefWidth="243.0" text="1" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="six" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="219.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="115.0" prefWidth="206.0" stylesheets="@FXMLDocument.css" text="6" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="seven" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="216.0" layoutY="219.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="115.0" prefWidth="206.0" stylesheets="@FXMLDocument.css" text="7" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="multi" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="628.0" layoutY="9.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="106.0" prefWidth="243.0" text="x" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="add" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="429.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="109.0" prefWidth="243.0" text="+" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="dot" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="422.0" layoutY="429.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="109.0" prefWidth="243.0" text="." textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="divide" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="9.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="109.0" prefWidth="243.0" text="÷" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="backspace" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="109.0" prefWidth="243.0" text="→" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="minus" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="109.0" prefWidth="243.0" text="-" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="equals" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="109.0" prefWidth="243.0" text="=" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="clearall" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="109.0" prefWidth="243.0" text="C" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="AZURE" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="clear" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="109.0" prefWidth="243.0" text="CE" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <Button fx:id="zero" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="436.0" layoutY="674.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="107.0" prefWidth="410.0" text="0" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="50.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="nine" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="230.0" layoutY="674.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="107.0" prefWidth="206.0" text="9" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="50.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="eight" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="674.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onKeyPressed="#KeyAction" prefHeight="107.0" prefWidth="206.0" text="8" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="50.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button cacheShape="false" centerShape="false" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="261.0" layoutY="101.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#send2sceneconver" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="162.0" scaleShape="false" text="Converter" visible="false">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <TabPane layoutX="888.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="757.0" prefWidth="235.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="Memory">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="715.0" prefWidth="241.0">
                     <children>
                        <TextArea editable="false" layoutX="-222.0" layoutY="72.0" prefHeight="690.0" prefWidth="235.0" promptText="Memory" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="38.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </TextArea>
                        <Button layoutY="690.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="114.0" text="M+">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <Button layoutX="120.0" layoutY="690.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="115.0" text="MC">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                     </children></AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="Notes">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TextArea layoutX="19.0" layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="715.0" prefWidth="235.0" promptText="Notes" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </TextArea>
                     </children></AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
      <Label fx:id="display" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" layoutX="23.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="202.0" prefWidth="811.0" text="0" textAlignment="RIGHT">
         <font>
            <Font size="96.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

```
I was wanting it to do [blank] if [blank] key pressed, but it caused a lot of error messages that I tried to read but did not make it.
```

Comment: For `(EventHandler<? super KeyEvent>) root` to be a valid cast, `root` must be of a type which implements EventHandler.  The root of your FXML is an AnchorPane, which, as you can see in the ‘All Implemented Interfaces’ section of the [documentation for the AnchorPane class](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html), only implements two interfaces, and neither is EventHandler.  You will want to write your own class which implements `EventHandler<KeyEvent>`.

Comment: But did you stop trying to cast `root` to `EventHandler`? Simply adding a separate `EventHandler` implementation won't suddenly make `root` an instance of `EventHandler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so to start off I would give java naming conventions a quick google after you fix your code. Next this is how I would solve the issue there are many different ways this can be done.

First we need remove all the onKeyActions in your FXML so anywhere you see `onKeyPressed="#KeyAction"` delete it

Next we need a function to replace this(your old onKeyPressed) so I have mocked out an example for digit 1 and 2

```
public void initKeyActions(Scene scene){
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(keyAction ->{
        System.out.println(keyAction.getCode());
        if(keyAction.getCode()==KeyCode.DIGIT1)
            one.fire();//Fires the necessary button
        else if(keyAction.getCode()==KeyCode.DIGIT2)
            two.fire();
        //Continue as I don't want to type these all out
    });
}
```

After that we need to call the function and pass the scene so we need to change how you initialize your fxml so that you can access the controller so do something like this

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());

    FXMLDocumentController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.initKeyActions(scene);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

After you implement all of your buttons it should be working as expected let me know if you have any other questions